# How to delete all plugin references in database?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

How does one completely remove a plugin from WordPress?

I have deleted the plugin via WordPress admin and then reinstalled, problem persists.

I see 8 records in cmsoptions table referencing the offending plugin. Since WP Admin drags to a grinding crawl with the plugin active, and for weeks the plugin was working just fine, I have to conclude that the problem exists due to the plugin references in the DB.

If anyone has the inside word on completely obliterating a plugin from WP, please do share.

Comment: I'd say that it depends a lot on what kind of plugin, and where it exists (in which tables). In your case, I'd do a DELETE FROM ... WHERE ... SQL-query. Other times, I'd do an UPDATE ... SET ... REPLACE...

Comment: can't delete as the references are part of serialized entries. Kind of a hassle to update set replace, everything seems so freaking hacked in WP. Plugin installation suggests 777 permissions, nice

Comment: As I said. It depends what kind of plugin we're talking about. What is the name of the plugin? It's not hacked in WP, it's flexible. If the plugin installation suggests 0777 permissions, then it sounds like a bad developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The the options API (http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) is open to the plugin to store whatever data it wishes (under whatever name it wishes).  You'd have to search the plugin code to see what it is storing (and how) in order to get rid of the offending data.

The issue isn't with WordPress, it's with the plugin.  WordPress is a framework and can't take responsibility for whatever gets built on top of it (ie plugins).  It's like blaming a hammer for a poorly built house.